# Best way to distinguish between scalar, list and dict arguments in Python?

Tags: python, types, python-2.7, polymorphism

I want a function that normally takes in an argument of type X where X is either a scalar, a list, or a dict, and returns a list of X's with the same key values, based on other information.

```
def foo(info, k):
   return [bar(item,k) for item in processInfo(info)]

def bar(item, keydata):
   # pseudocode follows.
   # What we want to do is return an output of parallel type to the input key k,
   # using the key data to lookup information from the input item.
   if keydata is a scalar:
      return item[keydata]
   elif keydata is a list:
      return [item[k] for k in keydata]
   elif keydata is a dict:
      return dict((k,item[v]) for (k,v) in keydata.iteritems())
   else:
      raise ValueError('bar expects a scalar, list, or dict')
```

My question is, how can I dispatch between the three types?

---

edit: A string is to be interpreted as a scalar, not a list/iterable. Tuples are to be interpreted as iterable.

edit 2: I want duck typing, not strict typing.

Comment: what if an object can exhibit both behaviours of a list and a dict?

Comment: then behavior for dict-like items takes precedence over behavior for iterable items

Comment: This question needs renaming, as it's the best one for determining the difference between dict and list, not just between scalar and nonscalar as the title implies. I keep skipping over it in searches.

Comment: just reworded... how's the title now?

Comment: I've added a minor tweak, but yes much better thanks.

Comment: Note that behaviour for dict-like items should take precedence even when the choice is between a dict and a list of dict. In this case, try the single-record version first and then fall back to the multi-record version on an AttributeError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how strict you want to be with your input. The `isinstance` approach forces you to specify the types to accept (I.e., no duck-typing). It works as long as your users are only passing in those classes or subtypes of those classes.  You can also try to distinguish parameters by the methods they support. An example of this would be

**Edit**: added the special case for strings

```
if isinstance(keydata, basestring):
    # special case to avoid considering strings as containers
    # for python 3.x use str instead of basestring
    return item[keydata]
try:
    return dict((k,item[v]) for (k,v) in keydata.iteritems())
except AttributeError:
    # it's not a dict-like
    pass
try:
    return [item[k] for k in keydata]
except TypeError:
    # it's not iterable
return item[keydata]
```

The choice of control flow depends on how flexible you want to be, and also how you want yo deal with ambiguous cases. Eg, is a string considered a sequence of characters or a scalar?

Comment: see my edits in the question. string is a scalar. (for my purposes)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to special-case strings (and unicodes, I assume!) and leave everything else duck-typed? Otherwise you need to specify in more detail what exactly makes strings so special :-)

Comment: Yes... it is ok to special-case strings. Strings are strings. :-)

Comment: @JasonS, why did you accept this answer when it doesn't do the right thing with strings?

Comment: Because it gave me the right approach to take for my application.

Comment: ...but Mark has a good point. I'll unaccept... but would reaccept if you follow-through on your comment about special-casing strings.

Comment: Strings, special cased :-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to do things in the proper order since `str` and `dict` types are iterable.

```
from collections import Iterable, Mapping  # in Python 3 use from collections.abc

def bar(item, keydata):
    if isinstance(keydata, Mapping):
        return {k: item[v] for (k,v) in keydata.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(keydata, Iterable) and not isinstance(keydata, str):
        return [item[k] for k in keydata]
    return item[keydata]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the new fancy stuff :) by import collections

```
>>> isinstance([], collections.Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance({}, collections.Mapping)
True
```

You should also consider looking at the [types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) module

Comment: `isinstance(''. collections.Sequence)` is `True` too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters shouldn't it be :) I would also say a tuple is a scalar since it is hashable :)

Comment: I'd call them scalars not because they are hashable but because they are immutable, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if isinstance(keydata,(int,float,str)): #scalar

elif isinstance(keydata,(list,tuple)):#iterable

elif isinstance(keydata,dict):#dictionary
```

maybe?? (Im probably missing a few types) ...

Comment: `str` is an interesting case, it can act both as a scalar and an iterable.

Comment: oh crap, that makes life more difficult, because I want to treat a string as a scalar, not as an iterable.

Comment: Test against the [ABC types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) instead.

Comment: @MarkRansom: it is a iterable scalar... There is no such distinction in Python, really.

Comment: This is python 2.7, not python 3

Comment: @JasonS: They exist for [Python 2.7 too](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use type, but isinstance is recommended according to http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

```
if type(asd) in (int, str):
    print 'asd is int or str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the information!

I ended up doing this, since I had to do some preprocessing of the `keydata` prior to iterating over the information:

```
def asKVlists(keydata):
    # return a tuple (keys, values, isScalar)
    # where keys and values are iterable
    if not isinstance(keydata, basestring):
        # check for dict behavior:
        try:
            return zip(*keydata.iteritems()) + [False]
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        # otherwise check for list behavior
        # make sure we can iterate over it
        try:
            iter(keydata)
            return (None, keydata, False)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return (None, (keydata,), True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_scalar(x):
    return hasattr(x, 'lower') or not hasattr(x, '__iter__')
```

Then you never have to worry about failing an `isinstance` because of somebody implementing an iterable subclassed from something unexpected.

Comment: But then I have to worry about somebody implementing an iterable with a `lower()` attribute or method.